# New MAUI Project Won't Build - Error not compatible with net6.0-android31.0

Tags: android, maui, maui-android

I'm creating a new MAUI project and have set to long term support version .NET 6.0. Out of the gate the project will not build and throws the below error. How will the project not build right after being created?

I have downloaded Android SDK versions from 28 - 33. Visual Studio 2022.

Here is my configuration on the Android Block of the Project Properties.

What do I need to do to resolve the dependencies of this brand new project for build?

[image]

```
Package Xamarin.AndroidX.ExifInterface 1.3.2.2 is not compatible with net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package Xamarin.AndroidX.ExifInterface 1.3.2.2 supports: monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the maui project, you need to use the nuget package or library which supports the version .NET 6.0 or .NET 7.0(depend on the target framework in your project).

And I have checked the last version of the nuget package `Xamarin.AndroidX.ExifInterface` you mentioned. The `Xamarin.AndroidX.ExifInterface 1.3.3.1` or higher is compatible with net6.0-android31.0. So you can update the package to version 1.3.3.2.

I have tested `Xamarin.AndroidX.ExifInterface 1.3.3.2` with a new maui .net 6.0 project and it can build successfully.