# MAUI: Build issues when upgrading Xamarin Forms App to MAUI

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I am migrating my `Xamarin Forms` app to MAUI using upgrade assistant. My app contains android and iOS projects. I used **.Net 6** for the Migration.

I have upgraded the solution(not upgraded the android and iOS projects) and deleted `bin and obj` folders. Then I clean the project and done Rebuild.

But I am getting below errors when rebuilding the project.

> 1. Error : XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ContentPage".
> 2. Error : XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "Frame".
> 3. Error : XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "Application".
> 4. Project targets 'net6.0-android;net6.0-ios'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v13.0'.
> 5. Project targets 'net6.0-android;net6.0-ios'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0'.
> 6. Project is not compatible with monoandroid13.0 Project supports:
>    net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
>    net6.0-ios16.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
> 7. Project is not compatible with xamarinios10 Project supports:
>    net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
>    net6.0-ios16.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
> 8. Version conflict detected for Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser. Install/reference Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser 1.4.0.1 directly to project to resolve this issue.
>    Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies 6.0.553 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.4.0.1)
>    Xam.Plugin.HtmlLabel 5.1.0 -> Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.0 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.3.0.5 && < 1.4.0).
> 9. The target platform must be set to Windows (usually by including '-windows' in the TargetFramework property) when using Windows Forms or WPF, or referencing projects or packages that do so.

**Fixes I have tried for the above issues:**

**1 to 3:** Found a solution [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13666) and added that code snippet in my Solution.csproj, but no change in those errors.

```
<Target
    Name="_ValidateMauiDoesNotHaveXamarinForms"
    BeforeTargets="_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform"
    Condition="'$(MauiDisableXamarinFormsValidation)' != 'True'">
    <Error
        Code="MA001"
        Text="This project or a dependency has imported the Xamarin.Forms packages. .NET MAUI is not compatible with Xamarin.Forms and is unable to build. Please remove Xamarin.Forms or the project/package dependency that is using Xamarin.Forms."
        Condition="'$(_XFTargetsImported)' == 'true'"/>
</Target>
```

**4th issue:** Similar issue found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/1743), but I didn't get what to do with that.

**5th issue:** Similar issue found [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/13201), but I didn't get what to do with that.

**6th issue:** Similar issue found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233071/new-maui-project-wont-build-error-not-compatible-with-net6-0-android31-0), but I didn't get what to do with that.

**7th issue:** Similar issue found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233071/new-maui-project-wont-build-error-not-compatible-with-net6-0-android31-0), but I didn't get what to do with that.

**8th issue:** I tried to install the `Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser - 1.4.0.1` to the android project for fixing that issue, but I am getting below error, I am able to install the version `1.3.0.6`.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyProject.Android'.

**9th issue:** I don't have windows project, so I don't know why this error showing. I found a solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1136), but below is my code on solution.csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseMaui>True</UseMaui>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Update**

I have added the following to the ios project .csproj file for fixing the "doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-ios/ios-arm64'".

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

1. I have added the `<SingleProject>true</SingleProject>` property into my Android project's .csproj file under the first/main property group, closed VS, deleted Bin, Obj, .vs folders for fixing the android physical device availability issue.
2. Set all of the files' build action to AndroidResource in the Resource folder on the Android platform and set BundleResource in the iOS platform.
3. For fixing the below kind of Cannot resolve type errors, I set the Xaml build action to MauiXaml from Embedded Resource.
4. Error : XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ContentPage". Error : XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "Frame". Error : XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "Application".

After all these fixes also I am facing some other build issues. I am adding it below:

1. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error NETSDK1136 The target platform must be set to Windows (usually by including '-windows' in the TargetFramework property) when using Windows Forms or WPF, or referencing projects or packages that do so. MyProject.iOS C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.Shared.targets 250
2. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error NU1107 Version conflict detected for Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser. Install/reference Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser 1.4.0.1 directly to project MyProject to resolve this issue. MyProject -> Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies 6.0.553 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.4.0.1) MyProject -> Xam.Plugin.HtmlLabel 5.1.0 -> Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.0 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.3.0.5 && < 1.4.0). MyProject E:\My Projects\Xamarin\MyProject-MyProject-app\MyProject\MyProject\MyProjectMyProject.csproj 1
3. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error NU1202 Package GMImagePicker.Xamarin 2.5.1 is not compatible with net6.0-ios16.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package GMImagePicker.Xamarin 2.5.1 supports: xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) MyProjectMyProject.iOS E:\My Projects\Xamarin\MyProject-MyProject-app\MyProject\MyProject.iOS\MyProjectMyProject.iOS.csproj 1
4. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error APT2144 invalid file path 'E:\My Projects\Xamarin\MyProject-MyProject-app\MyProject\MyProject.Android\obj\Debug\net6.0-android\res\resources\xml_\file_paths.xml'. MyProjectMyProject.Android C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.485\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets 123

**Update**

I have fixed the `Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser` issue (2nd issue in the top list) by installing a few NuGet packages on Android and solution project.

**On Android:**

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser">
  <Version>1.4.0.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData">
  <Version>2.4.1.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material">
  <Version>1.6.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.UI">
  <Version>2.4.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

**On Solution**

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser" Version="1.4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData" Version="2.4.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core" Version="1.8.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.UI" Version="2.4.2" />
```

Comment: After running the upgrade-assistant tool, additional effort will be required to complete the migration, Please refer to [Upgrade a Xamarin.Forms app to .NET MAUI with the .NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/upgrade-assistant).

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT On where I can view the additional set up? Could you please share any blog for that?

Comment: Sure, there many excellent tutorials and videos for that whole process, you can refer to [Upgrading from Xamarin to .NET MAUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCtkjz51bJ8) and [Migrating & Upgrading Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXmSmv5ifkk).

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT In the first youtube tutorial, they are creating a new MAUI project with the same name and adding files into it. My project is already available on stores. So if we create a new MAUI project and move all the files into it, is it approve by the stores?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I have fixed a few issues and I have updated the question with that details with the current issues. Could you please have a look?

Comment: I've taken a look into your current issue, for issue 3, the package[GMImagePicker.Xamarin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GMImagePicker.Xamarin) seems not being compatible with net6.0-ios16.1. You may need a maui version for the package.

Comment: @SreejithSree Thanks for the response! I've done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [The .NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/upgrade-assistant?tabs=vswin) to upgrade Xamarin.Forms projects to .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI). For more information about .NET Upgrade Assistant, including the other app types it can convert, see Overview of [the .NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview).

In addition, if you want to manually upgrade a multi-project Xamarin.Forms app to a multi-project .NET MAUI app, please take care of the listed items below:

- [Namespace
  changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-multi-project#namespace-changes)
- [API
  changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-multi-project#api-changes)
- [Color
  changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-multi-project#color-changes)
- [Layout
  changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-multi-project#layout-changes)
- [Custom layout
  changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-multi-project#custom-layout-changes)
- [Device
  changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-multi-project#device-changes)
- [Map
  changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-multi-project#map-changes)
- [Other
  changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-multi-project#other-changes)